# Show that the series is convergent/divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty = \frac{\sqrt[3]{n}\times(-1)^n}{n-1}$

I can prove it does converge, but not absolutely by using the comparison test and p-test. But to determine if it is convergent by the alternating series test, I could not prove it. I am stuck between $\sqrt[3]n$ and $\sqrt[3]{n+1}$

Comment: You mean you cannot show that $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{n+1}}n<\frac{\sqrt[3]n}{n-1}$$? If so, cube both sides.

Comment: but n+1 > n while 1/n^3 <1/(n-1)^3

Comment: You are not being clear on what your problem here is.

Comment: Sorry just edited it. So $\sqrt[3]{n+1}$ > $\sqrt[3]{n}$ but 1/n < 1/(n-1).

Comment: So? You need to show that $\sqrt[3]{n+1}/n<\sqrt[3]n/(n-1)$. Have you followed through on my hint by cubing both sides.

Comment: But is it still the same when n+1 > n and $\frac{1}{n^3}$ < $\frac{1}{(n-1)^3}$ ?

Comment: Why do you continue to try and separate the inequality into different parts? $2\times4<3\times3$ is obvious, but splitting it into $2<3$ and $4>3$ tells you nothing; so don't do that?

Comment: Ok so it's clear that $\frac{1}{n}$ < $\frac{1}{n-1}$. If I multiply it by $\sqrt[3]{n}$, it will become $\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{n}$ < $\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{n-1}$, but  $\frac{\sqrt[3]{n+1}}{n}$ > $\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{n}$ < $\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{n-1}$

Comment: And obviously that's the wrong approach... Here's a similar example:$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}n<\frac{\sqrt n}{n-1}\Leftarrow\frac{n+1}{n^2}<\frac n{(n-1)^2}\Leftarrow(n+1)(n-1)^2<n^3\Leftarrow\dots$$

Comment: Can you follow from this example rather than trying the same thing over and over, expecting it to work even though it fails every time?

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt[3]n}{n}$ is convergent. The
difference with your series is
$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]n}{n}
-\frac{\sqrt[3]n}{n-1}\right)$
which is absolutely convergent. So your series is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

It's of course alternating and the absolute values are $\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{n+1}$ which is decreasing from a certain index onwards (which is enough): compute the derivative of $f(x)= \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{x+1}$ and check when it becomes $< 0$.

Comment: Using derivatives is somewhat overkill?

Comment: It's clear intuitively. The $x$ increases a lot faster than the root term so order reasoning shows it must be eventually decreasing. The derivative is just a formal way to show it. @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: But is taking a derivative necessary for that sort of thing? Not to mention, applying derivatives and checking for $f'<0$ isn't easier than simply checking $f(x+1)<f(x)$.